# Content of button adapts size according to button?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want to resize `content` within a `button` so that when I "resize" my window, `buttons` also gets resized but size of `content` within `button` remains unchanged?

What should I do in order to make contents resized WRT button size.

Thanks, Faisal

PS: I am using *GRID* layout in *WPF*.
[image]

Comment: Create font size behavior like below solution.

[How to automatically scale font size for a group of controls][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641473/how-to-automatically-scale-font-size-for-a-group-of-controls

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq, while I applaud the fact that you have come back here and want to show the users your final solution, I should point out that it is not correct to do that by editing someone else's answer. It's probably best to add a question edit or update to the bottom of *your question* to show that kind of stuff.

Comment: I got it. I will do the same way[of course as you told] next time. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way that I can think of you doing that is for you to use a [`ViewBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) element inside your `Button`s:

```
<Button>
    <ViewBox>
        <!--Your Button content--> 
    </ViewBox>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best approach to this issue would be to actually make a tiny converter which would be dynamically controlling the text size.

Here is an example of such a converter:

C#

```
using System.Globalization;

public class FontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double actualHeight = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        int fontSize = (int)(actualHeight * .5);
        return fontSize;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then here is the usage of this class within your xaml:

XAML

```
...
<Window.Resources>
    <l:FontSizeConverter x:Key="FSConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<Grid>   
    <Button Content="Dat Button" FontSize="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}, Converter={StaticResource FSConverter}}"/>    
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you will have any issues with that.

K.

Comment: -1. This should be achieved with a simple `Viewbox` without resorting to procedural code.

Comment: Its just another solution to a problem, and a valid one which could be used as a good alternative in case you cant use a `ViewBox`.